# Nominal voltage of a battery with or without ESR?

Tags: voltage, batteries

I am reading a calculation document which has calculated nominal voltage at MPV(50%) with the open circuit voltage from the datasheet, but from what I have read so far on different forums its the voltage which we should observe for most of the use of the battery at the terminals which means that the nominal voltage also includes the drop across the internal resistance and not just an OCV, is my assumption correct ?

Comment: The ESR is **always present**, it never just disappears (become zero). You are correct that there will be a voltage drop across the battery's series resistor. Did you think about what the voltage drop will be across this series resistor when the current drawn from the battery is small and when it is large? When we measure the OCV how much current flows? So what will then be the voltage drop?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie OCV voltage would mean we never draw current from battery because the circuit is open , that time the voltage drop across the internal resistance is zero as there is no current flowing in a closed loop but my question when calculating nominal voltage the user just multiplied the OCV(@50%) with the number of cells in series and shouldnt we be subtracting this (ESR*peak current) from this voltage ?

Comment: Of course "nominal voltage" does not include the effect of a load current (losses in the ESR).  It *could not* as the current is unknown!  Only a spec at a stated current could include that.